# Drawing camera lines until frustum rectangle using Cesium?

Tags: cesium

I'm trying to draw a nice polygon like this to create my own sensor since we must to pay to have one from Cesium.

[image]

My goal is to make realtime viewshed analysis. For now I'm just making some tests. I don't know how to perform the viewshed "shadows". Will try to make it using the camera light and shadows.

To achieve this I need to 1) draw my own polygon like one of the picture but I confess I even know how to start. 2) use the Cesium Camera [debug](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/DebugCameraPrimitive.html). This will draw a simple polygon simulating the FOV. Easy to do but...

The FOV polygon are going too far ( thru earth going to one galaxy far away...).

[image]
[image]

So how can I limit the "camera range" to the frustum (the rectangle near the camera, or the POV) ?

If someone have a more elegant solution I will gladly accept it.

[My code until now...](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html#c=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)

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    infoBox: false,
    selectionIndicator: false,
    shadows: true,
    terrainShadows: Cesium.ShadowMode.ENABLED,
    shouldAnimate: true,
    terrainProvider: Cesium.createWorldTerrain()
});

var scene = viewer.scene;
var ellipsoid = scene.globe.ellipsoid;

var instance = new Cesium.GeometryInstance({
  geometry : new Cesium.EllipseGeometry({
      center : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-100.0, 20.0),
      semiMinorAxis : 500000.0,
      semiMajorAxis : 1000000.0,
      rotation : Cesium.Math.PI_OVER_FOUR,
      vertexFormat : Cesium.VertexFormat.POSITION_AND_ST
  }),
  id : 'object returned when this instance is picked and to get/set per-instance attributes'
});
scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.Primitive({
  geometryInstances : instance,
  appearance : new Cesium.EllipsoidSurfaceAppearance({
    material : Cesium.Material.fromType('Checkerboard')
  })
}));


var west = -45;
var south = -24;
var east = -40;
var north = -20;    
var homeLocation = Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(west, south, east, north);


viewer.camera.flyTo({
    destination : homeLocation
});

var camera = new Cesium.Camera(scene);
//camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_RECTANGLE = homeLocation;
//camera.position = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
//camera.direction = Cesium.Cartesian3.negate(Cesium.Cartesian3.UNIT_Z, new Cesium.Cartesian3());
//camera.up = Cesium.Cartesian3.clone(Cesium.Cartesian3.UNIT_Y);
camera.frustum.fov = Cesium.Math.PI_OVER_THREE;
camera.frustum.near = 1.0;
camera.frustum.far = 2.0;

camera.setView({
    destination : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-45,-24, 15000.0)
});

scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.DebugCameraPrimitive({
  camera : camera,
  color : Cesium.Color.YELLOW
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a very good job to keep the "sensor plugin" project active (it was free once) [here](https://github.com/xagriff/cesium-sensors/tree/master/Examples) and a pendding pull request to update to Cesium 1.59 [here](https://github.com/Flowm/cesium-sensor-volumes), finally I have a good start point to my long journey.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do something similar and reached out to the Cesium Team. They reacted very quickly and in version 1.70 (June), we should have a new feature available :)
See:

https://community.cesium.com/t/debugcameraprimitive-depth/9603

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But I conclude this is useless without any kind of event callback so this is not really a "sensor" ... it is just a polygon floating .. is not what I need because it become too hard to implement like the first picture.